# AFNetworking 2.0 JSON queue

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-ws, afnetworking-2

in AFNetworking 1.3 i enqueue some operations in this way:

- Create many AFHTTPRequestOperation with success and failure block
- Create enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations with all operations and when all are completed, call the completionBlock for the final step.

Unfortunally this dont works well with my webservice. I've read in internet and all say to try it with Afnetworking 2.0, but, how can i have the same behavior ?

Simply i want to add on queue some operations (and set for each one success block to do something), and call another method when ALL of them are completed.

How can i do it in AFNetworking 2.0 ? My response is in JSON format.